# Issue with selecting screenshots from the gallery on Xiaomi devices in an app developed with Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, xiaomi

I'm having an issue with my app developed with Expo. At a certain point, I used the 'expo-media-library' and 'expo-image-picker' libraries to allow users to select photos from their device's gallery. So far, all devices can do this without any problem. However, on Xiaomi devices, screenshots taken on the phone don't appear for users to select, while on devices like iPhone, Samsung, LG, etc., this works fine. What could be causing this? Is it a permission problem?

I have already tried to check if it was a permission problem in the code, but it might be on the device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.